# How do I change text color inside a nav bar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've tried to use one of the recommended bootstrap 4 navbar styles. I pasted the code inside my project and all worked well. The only problem is that I've changed the background color from dark to white. Because of that text inside the navbar went invisible. I was trying many ways on how to change the text color to black so you can see the text but it didn't work and I can't figure out how do I change the color of the text from white to black.

I've tried adding the text-black class inside one of the navbar classes which didn't work as well.

Thanks for any help.

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<section id="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-white static-top text-black">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/logo_5_150x60.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: One moment, just trying to decode your username 

Comment: have you tried with ```!important```

Comment: if your text is white, can't you remove the bg-white class?

Comment: K go-ahead but primarily answer the question, please. Thanks.

Comment: In your CSS, `#navigation{ color: #000 !important; }`

Comment: Change the `navbar-dark` to `navbar-light` if you're using a white background. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Comment: Guys the question is answered by Miroslav Glamuzina. Thanks to everyone for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `navbar-dark` class on your `<nav>` element is the one setting the text color.
Change the `navbar-dark` to `navbar-light` when using light background colors.

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#color-schemes

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<section id="navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white static-top text-black">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/logo_5_150x60.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some css to `#navigation *` and set the color using `color`.

```css
#navigation * {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<section id="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-white static-top text-black">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/logo_5_150x60.png" alt="">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Hope this helps